# loop in php condition wrong condition

Tags: php, loops

please tell me why not display "ok" if the condition is true?
I can not understand why "no" is displayed if the condition is triggered.

[image]

```
<?php if (get_number() == "ok") {
    echo "ok";
}
else {
    echo "no";
}
function get_number() {
    $number = rand(1, 10);
    echo $number;
    if ($number == 5) {
        return "ok";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        get_number();
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: A side question: why do you test the return of a function that is supposed to only return "ok" ? if it is only for test purpose, you could do a simple `var_dump()` to see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your else condition from `get_number();` to `return get_number();` to make recursive call.

Also, why you are using 2 return statements in if condition ?

```
return "ok";
return false;
```

You can keep first one, remove second return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` block doesn't return anything, so unless you get the number 5 on the first attempt, it will go to the `else` block, that calls itself but won't actually return any value to the initial call.

If a function doesn't return anything, you will get `NULL` instead.

Add a `return` statement in the `else`-block as well to make the returned alue bubble up all the way to the initial call.

```php
if ($number == 5) {
    return "ok";
}
else {
    return get_number();
}
```

Btw, I hope this isn't real code but just some test, since it's basically just an overcomplicated way of echoing `ok`. It should never be able to reach `echo 'no';`

Answer (score -2):

rand(1, 10) this will return a random number generated like this 183995 and you added condition that if ($number == 5) then return "ok" but in your case, it will not satisfy and always goes in else condition so you get no as output

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Let me explain it. You must know every function must return something unless it's `void`.

In the else block, where you make a recursive call to `get_number()`, you are not returning the result of the recursive call.

Change `get_number();` to `return get_number();`

```
<?php

if (get_number() == "ok") {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "no";
}

function get_number()
{
    $number = rand(1, 10);
    echo $number;
    if ($number == 5) {
        return "ok";
    } else {
        return get_number(); // Return the result of the recursive call
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: why you are posting same answer. @Kedar has already answered the same.

Comment: @DhrumanDesai I typed the answer but posted it later. I was busy, that's why. I wasn't aware someone already answered it.